# Calculating deep total and average of table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php code to calculate to dispaly login time duration and count.
But I want to end of table I want to calculate total duration time and login count at then end of each column.
At the end of rove I want to calculate average login duration and average login count which is total duration/number of item. But cant do it.
Can you give me a hint?

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT connection_log.user, `count(*) as         'connection_count', sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,connection_log.logondate, connection_log.logoffdate)) as `connection_time`
FROM connection_log 
INNER JOIN users ON connection_log.user=users.user 
WHERE users.groups 
LIKE '%cpg_sirket_dyo%' and connection_log.logondate>='2015-09-01 00:00:00' and connection_log.logoffdate<'2015-10-01 00:00:00' 
group by connection_log.user 
order by connection_count desc",$con);
echo '<table width="80%" border="1" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">';
echo "  <tr>
    <th> Row number </th>
    <th> Username </th>
    <th> Total login count </th>
    <th> Total login duration(min.) </th>
    </tr> ";
$counter = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) 
{
echo "  <tr>
        <td> ". $counter ." </td>
        <td> ". $row['user'] . "</td>
        <td> ". $row['connection_count'] ." </td>
        <td> ". $row['connection_time']  ." </td>
        </tr> ";
$counter++;
}

//SUM CALCULATION
//NEED HERE!
//
echo "</table><br>\n";
echo $icounter. " Items<br>\n";

mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store all the information in an array and calculate the mean at the end:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) 
{
echo "  <tr>
        <td> ". $counter ." </td>
        <td> ". $row['user'] . "</td>
        <td> ". $row['connection_count'] ." </td>
        <td> ". $row['connection_time']  ." </td>
        </tr> ";
$connection_count[] = $row['connection_count'];
$connection_time[] = $row['connection_time'];

$counter++;

}

$meanCount = array_sum($connection_count)/count($connection_count);
$meanTime = array_sum($connection_time)/count($connection_time);

// do what ever you like with it

echo "</table><br>\n";
```

Hope this helps